# Cookie Editor for IE?

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer

I need to manually edit some cookies in IE 7 to do some testing. Firefox has decent CookieEditor plugins available. Have you used any reliable cookie editors for IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know of a utility for viewing/editing cookies on IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839967/anyone-know-of-a-utility-for-viewing-editing-cookies-on-ie)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_cookies_view.html). (It's not just for viewing, you can use it to edit). I am a big fan of nirsoft, really great software.

Comment: CAUTION!  I followed the link above to the nirsoft site, and when I tried to download their Cookie editor, Sophos antivirus detected malware "Map/BredoZp-B" in the download zip.  Googled that virus name.  Apparently it's a trojan that installs a botnet on your computer, among other malicious behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how permanently you need the cookies edited, [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) filters might also work for you.

Comment: Have not explored the Fiddler filters. Will try soon. Thanks!